# Sum array in MIPS conditionally skipping certain numbers

Tags: assembly, mips

Here's the problem I am trying to solve:

> Return the sum of the numbers in the array, returning 0 for an empty array. Except the number 13 is very unlucky, so it does not count and numbers that come immediately after a 13 also do not count.
>
> Examples:
>
> `sum13([1, 2, 2, 1]) → 6`
>
> `sum13([1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13]) → 4`
>
> `sum13([1, 2, 2, 1, 13]) → 6`

This function takes an array and array length as parameters.

I have set `$a0` to be the array address and `$a1` to be the array length. `$v0` is the sum.

This is what I have so far but it does not pass the tests I have written.

```
.globl sum13

.data 
arrayData: .word 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13
la $a0, arrayData
li $a1, 6

sum13:
    li $t2, 0   # t2 is the counter
    
loop:
    lw $t1, 0($a0)      # current address
    
    bge $t2, $a1, endSum13      # end of array check, a1 is array length
    beq $t1, 13, isThirteen     # checks if current val == 13
    
    add $v0, $v0, $t1   # adding current val to the sum v0
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    # increment counter
    addi $a0, $a0, 4    # increment address
    j loop
    
isThirteen:
    addi $t2, $t2, 2    # increment counter by 2
    addi $a0, $a0, 8    # increment address by 8
    j loop
    
endSum13:
    jr $ra
```

My code works when 13 is not present in the array so I think the problem may lay in how I am skipping over 13 and the following value when incrementing the counter by 2 and the address by 8. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: I am using a separate test suite but the only registers that function as parameters for data are $a0, and $a1. $a0 is the array address and $a1 is the array length. The final output is the sum, which comes out on $v0. I have updated the post with data that I have been using, I think this is how you would format it but I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Your code basically works for me. The only change I made is `sum13: li $v0, 0`. Are you doing this? I'd also move `bge $t2, $a1, endSum13
` to the top of the loop to avoid an out of bounds load, but it shouldn't matter.

Comment: You are missing the `.text` directive, which is generally used when putting `.data` up front.

Answer (score 1):

Your code pretty much works for me after setting `$v0` to 0 before attempting to accumulate on it. You may have neglected this.

`$t2` should start at 1, not 0, if you're using `bge` to end the loop.

I'd also move `bge $t2, $a1, endSum13` to the top of the loop to avoid an out of bounds load.

You have code in the `.data` area but I assume this is elided boilerplate.

```
.data 
arrayData: .word 1, 2, 13, 2, 1, 13

.text
main:
    la $a0, arrayData
    li $a1, 6
    jal sum13

    # print result
    move $a0 $v0
    li $v0 1
    syscall

    # exit
    li $v0 10
    syscall

sum13:
    li $v0, 0
    li $t2, 1   # t2 is the counter

loop:
    bge $t2, $a1, endSum13      # end of array check, a1 is array length

    lw $t1, 0($a0)      # current address
    beq $t1, 13, isThirteen     # checks if current val == 13

    add $v0, $v0, $t1   # adding current val to the sum v0
    addi $t2, $t2, 1    # increment counter
    addi $a0, $a0, 4    # increment address
    j loop

isThirteen:
    addi $t2, $t2, 2    # increment counter by 2
    addi $a0, $a0, 8    # increment address by 8
    j loop

endSum13:
    jr $ra
```